# How to apply a tint (on hover) to a div whose background image size is set to contain?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image. Due to design constraints that background image needs to have the size set to contain. I want to apply a tint to that image on hover, however the way I've set it up means the entire div tints rather than just the image.

I wondered if there was a CSS technique I wasn't aware of to achieve the effect I need, where only the background image itself tints rather than the entire div?

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f9cca07d4c42920d4d348c7/960x0.jpg?fit=scale');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease opacity 350ms;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container:hover .image::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like you, I do not know if there is a way or not. In some cases, I also add an extra layer to the image

Comment: Hi! Could you provide an example of what you mean by an extra layer to the image?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f9cca07d4c42920d4d348c7/960x0.jpg" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
}
div:hover img {
    filter: sepia(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f9cca07d4c42920d4d348c7/960x0.jpg?fit=scale');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease opacity 350ms;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.extraLayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease opacity 350ms;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.container:hover .image::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container:hover .extraLayer {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="extraLayer">
    <p style="color:white;">
      Draw what you want 
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f9cca07d4c42920d4d348c7/960x0.jpg?fit=scale');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease opacity 350ms;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container:hover .image::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Satish, I cannot have the image set to cover as it needs to be set to contain.

Comment: try img tag instead of using background image & Add this css                          
.image{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this would work in one instance but in another I need the images to be background so I can control the height with a percentage.